# Dependency injecting a service within another service in laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, service

#Background

Hi,

I've got a laravel codebase I've inherited. There are some third party APIs being used for assorted data services and I am attempting to make the software more testable. Some of these API calls are handled via clients and are shared using services.

In order to continue the testing, some services will need to call other services. With this I also am attempting to dependency inject them. I am having issues doing this.

### Setup

- laravel/framework: "^8.0.0

### Question

The following Service needs to be able to dependency inject another service in functions.

```php
namespace App\Services\ExampleService;

use App\Services\ExampleDependantService;

class SyncProfile
{
    // ...
}
```

I have attempted to inject at a function level (this is preferred):

```php
    public function sync(ExampleDependantService $exampleDependantService, /*...*/)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

I've also attempted to set this up at a class/constructor level:

```php
    protected ExampleDependantService $exampleDependantService;

    public function __construct(ExampleDependantService $exampleDependantService)
    {
        $this->exampleDependantService = $exampleDependantService;
    }
```

Both of these are unable to resolve the `ExampleDependantService` when tested, giving errors such as:

- `ArgumentCountError : Too few arguments to function App\Services\ExampleService\SyncProfile::__construct(), 0 passed in  [..]/SyncProfileTest.php on line 96 and exactly 1 expected ..`

To be clear, the `ExampleDependantService` is registered in `config/app.php`

```php
'providers' => [
    // ...
    App\Services\ExampleDependantService::class
    // ...
```

## Desired situation

- I should be able to call `$exampleService->sync()` in normal usage
- I should be able to call `$exampleService->sync($mockedExampleDependantService)` in test usage

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to pass parameters in the `register()` method of `AppServiceProvider`.
You need to set the dependency there as well like this:

```
$this->app->bind(SyncProfile::class, function (Application $app) {
        return new SyncProfile($app->make(ExampleDependantService::class));
    });
```

This way the dependency is available in the constructor of your service.